# Scikit-learn: Perform cross-validation on training data then fit the model on the test data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I wish to perform n-fold cross-validation method on training data and then fit the model with the optimised parameters on the test sub-set.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.3, 
                                                        random_state=1234)

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression() 
cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=10).split(y_train) # [Question: 1]
cv_score = cross_val_score(lm, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, scoring="r2")
```

My questions are:

- **[Question: 1]** Assuming it was a logistic regression, is this correct
  if I want to account for class inequality (check **12th line** of code)?
- **[Question: 2]** how can I fit the model from `cross_val_score` on the **X_test** data to predict the **y_test** data?

Answer (score 0):

- **[Question: 1]** Assuming it was a logistic regression, is this correct
  if I want to account for class inequality (check **12th line** of code)?

Yes

- **[Question: 2]** how can I fit the model from `cross_val_score` on the **X_test** data to predict the **y_test** data?

**You will need GridSearch. Then the best model can be retrieved and used for the test set.**

Example:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC(gamma="scale")
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=5)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

y_test = clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
```

More here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The cross_val returns the scores per i-fold based on the training data. What I would like though, is to use the coefficients/model from the training-cv and fit them on the test data. Any ideas how?